# No provider for PlatformRef error after upgrading to Angular2 RC5 in IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, angular, internet-explorer-10, angular-seed

I just upgraded to Angular2 RC5. The app loads fine in all browsers exception IE10. I get an exception "No provider for PlatformRef!" when I bootstrap the application. Everything worked fine in RC4. I saw some posts on the web about this exception, but they were all related to Meteor. I do not use meteor. My project is derived from AngularSeed (previous version that I updated manually to RC5). Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks!

In IE10, I get this error:

```
No provider for PlatformRef!  
{
  [functions]: ,
  context: <Permission denied>,
  injectors: [ ],
  keys: [ ],
  message: "No provider for PlatformRef!",
  name: "Error",
  stack: undefined,
  Symbol()_m.sovohbnexgu: undefined,
  Symbol()_n.sovohbnexgu: undefined,
  Symbol()_o.sovohbnexgu: undefined,
  Symbol(rxSubscriber)_p.sovohbnexgu: undefined
}
```

main.ts:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule }              from './app.module';

enableProdMode();
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

AppModule:

```
import { provide, NgModule, ExceptionHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { AppExceptionHandler } from './app.exceptionhandler';
import { AppRoutes } from './app.routes';
import { LogService, ... } from './services/';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
    imports: [BrowserModule,
              RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes),
              HttpModule,
              FormsModule],
    providers: [provide(ExceptionHandler, { useClass: AppExceptionHandler }), LogService, ...],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Dependencies versions:

- "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
- "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
- "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
- "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
- "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
- "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
- "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
- "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
- "es6-module-loader": "^0.17.8",
- "core-js": "^2.4.0",
- "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
- "systemjs": "0.19.27",
- "zone.js": "0.6.13",

---

Edit: If I try to add PlatformRef to the @NgModule imports, I get this error:

```
shims.js?1472473326356:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null(anonymous function) 
@ app.js?1472473326358:5getTransitiveModules 
@ app.js?1472473326358:5CompileMetadataResolver._getTransitiveNgModuleMetadata 
@ app.js?1472473326358:5CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata 
@ app.js?1472473326358:5RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents 
@ app.js?1472473326358:3RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents 
@ app.js?1472473326358:3RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync 
@ app.js?1472473326358:3PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone 
@ app.js?1472473326358:48PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule 
@ app.js?1472473326358:48bootstrapper 
@ app.js?1472473326358:57(anonymous function) 
[...]
```

I get this stack on IE:

```
"TypeError: Unable to get property 'type' of undefined or null reference
   at Anonymous function (eval code:13673:13)
   at Call (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js?1472473192889:289:7)
   at forEach (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js?1472473192889:1295:7)
   at getTransitiveModules (eval code:13672:9)
   at CompileMetadataResolver.prototype._getTransitiveNgModuleMetadata (eval code:13387:13)
   at CompileMetadataResolver.prototype.getNgModuleMetadata (eval code:13259:17)
   at RuntimeCompiler.prototype._compileComponents (eval code:15845:13)
   at RuntimeCompiler.prototype._compileModuleAndComponents (eval code:15769:13)
   at RuntimeCompiler.prototype.compileModuleAsync (eval code:15746:13)
   at PlatformRef_.prototype._bootstrapModuleWithZone (eval code:9991:13)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove es6-shim from the dependencies. Works fine now.

Comment: W/o polyfills it says that there's no `Object.assign` method.

Comment: Was this problem resolved ?
I am also facing same issue and it is not solved after removing es6-shim.

Comment: Yeah, removing the es6-shim does not work at all as far as I can tell. IE still doesn't have support for Object.assign.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the same after importing `PlatformRef` from `@angular/core` and adding it to `imports` configuration of `NgModule` for your AppModule file.

Comment: I tried that, but I now get an error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null"

Comment: I also tried adding it to the providers list on the module, and it does not fix the issue.

Comment: where you get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null" error ?also provide in '@angular/core' is deprecated so you have to change your `ExceptionHandler` provider setting in Appmodule to `{ provide:ExceptionHandler,useClass: AppExceptionHandler  }`

Comment: Thank you! I updated the provide call and edited my question to give you the stack trace.

Comment: please check after changing `declarations: [AppComponent, ...]` to `declarations: [AppComponent]`.