# Upgrade from Angular 4 to 5: "NodeInvocationException: No provider for PlatformRef!"

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, asp.net-core, angular5

I've upgraded an app from Angular 4.2 to 5, but got this error:
 `unhandled exception occurred while processing the request`, more specifically:

> NodeInvocationException: No provider for PlatformRef! Error: No
>   provider for PlatformRef! at injectionError
>   (e:\myapp\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:12066:90)

The app also uses [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) and `ASP.NET Core`.

I have installed `node v9.1`, and `typescript 2.6.1`.

I also have updated `package.json`, with the command:

```
npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest
```

And afterwards, ran the following:

```
 npm install --save-dev @ngtools/webpack@latest
```

I've also used `HttpClient` instead of `Http`:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; 
.....
 getThings() {
        return this.http.get('/api/things');

  }
```

If I downgrade back Angular 4, the app works fine, is there anything in my line of thought that has been done incorrectly?

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207615/cannot-find-the-angular-common-http-module

Comment: did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39206501/2810015

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45207765/5510314

Comment: @Freeman;not working...

Comment: A detailed walkthrough that solved it for me: https://tw.saowen.com/a/ad07b7c1b317c677413543de1b1a44ec8f950c4dc3af8051670ae77be3d1f50a

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found a solving solution:
I've used this  [Angular 5 Asp Core template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RebaiHamidaTrabelsi.Angular5TemplateCore2)

I've updated dependecies to latest angular 5 version: `npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest`

```
npm install --save-dev @ngtools/webpack@latest
```

I've recompiled  `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js` (must have webpack installed globally:  `npm install -g webpack@2.5.1`)

I've replaced ClientApp/ASP files with my project files
Manully changed in `app.module`:

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

to

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

in services files instead of `Http`  I've used `HttpClient`:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Comment: `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js` helped me to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Two different things, which you can try:

1) import HttpClientModule at your NgModule's import array first.(If you are using HttpClient in your component)

2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/39206501/2810015

Note: to upgrade your application : https://onlyforcoder.blogspot.in/2017/11/angular-5-upgrade-your-project-To-Angular5.html

Comment: Hi,I've removed  es6-shim from package.json,in app.module I've replaced  HttpModule with HttpClientModule...but no fix.thanks.